# How do I correctly use COMMTIMEOUTS with OVERLAPPED IO mode reading from a Serial port

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port, communication

I am trying to use the overlapped IO mode on Windows 7/8 X64 to emulate the non blocking mode (**IO_NONBLOCK**) behavior supported by Linux's open flags.  The code here is part of the windows portion of a cross platform serial API.

I can open the COMM port in either blocking or non blocking (OVERLAPPED) mode using constructor parameters for the **SerialCommWnt** object.  As far as this question goes all my questions have to do with when the COMM port is opened in OVERLAPPED mode (as specified by a flow control constructor parameter).  For the Read method, I specify a timeout parameter, which upon successfully retrieving at least 1 byte of data from the serial port, should indicate the time remaining of the rTimeout parameter when data was in the serial comm's input buffer (I believe that the serial driver notifies the manual reset event in the overlapped structure when it receives any data).

I read many StackOverflow threads on how to handle these APIs, many of them refer to the Microsoft Win32 API.  The best information I can find so far is

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx
This API is confusing for Overlapped IO (expecially when it comes to passing a pointer to the number of bytes received when calling ReadFile in overlapped mode), but as far as I can tell, none of them addresses to how to correctly use the overlapped IO mode in combination with the COMMTIMEOUTS.  I spent the last couple of days experimenting with combinations of settings for both the COMMTIMEOUTS and the timeout parameter used with **::WaitForSingleObject**. Finally the combination that seems to mostly work is shown.  I have some reliability questions with regard to the timeouts associated with the manual reset event object associated with the overlapped IO structure and the COMMTIMEOUTS.   I am not entirely sure, but it seems that in order for a timeout to work correctly when reading form a serial port, it is mandatory to specify a timeout in the COMMTIMEOUTS.  I tried a combination where I disabled timeouts in the **SetCommTimeouts** and instead used an explicit timeout in the **::WaitForSingleObject**'s timeout parameter, but that did not work, instead I did it the other way around by specifying a timeout in the COMMTIMEOUTS and specifying INFINITE with the **::WaitForSingleObject** method call.  I'm not sure however if there can be situations where this will hang forever and if so how I can handle this.  I would appreciate any info on how to correctly handle potentially hanging here.

here is the method that I use to open the COMM port - in this case where I have timeout questions, I specify the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED.

```
    /**
     * Open the serial port using parameters set in theconstructor.<p>
     * The Port Number, Speed, Overlapped IO mode, #data bits &
     * async mode etc. are specified as constructor arguments.
     *
     * @return OS_FAILED, OS_SUCCESS
     */
    OsStatus
    SerialCommWnt::open()
    {
        // Critical Section
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock (mMutexGuard);
        OsStatus result = OS_FAILED;
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << "\\\\.\\COM" << mCommPort;
        std::string deviceName = os.str();
        DWORD dwFlagsAndAttrs = (mFlowControl ==
            SerialCommBase::FCTL_OVERLAPPED)?
            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED : 0;
        // open the underlying device for read and write
        mOsFileHandle = CreateFile (
            deviceName.c_str(),
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,                      //(share) 0:cannot share the COM port
            NULL,                   // no security attributes
            OPEN_EXISTING,          // COMM devices must use OPEN_EXISTING
            dwFlagsAndAttrs,        // optional FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED
            NULL);                  // hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
        if ( mOsFileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
            // reserve an 8k communications channel buffer (both directions)
            BOOL isOK = SetupComm(mOsFileHandle, 8200, 8200);
            // Omit the call to SetupComm to use the default queue sizes.
            // Get the current configuration.
            DCB dcb;
            SecureZeroMemory(&dcb, sizeof(DCB));
            isOK = GetCommState (mOsFileHandle, &dcb);
            if (isOK) {
                // Fill in the DCB: baud=125000, 8 data bits, even parity, 1 stop bit.
                // This is the standard baud rate. The card we have has a custom crystal
                // changing this baud rate to 125K.
                dcb.BaudRate = static_cast<DWORD>(mBaudRate);
                dcb.ByteSize = static_cast<BYTE>(mByteSize);
                // enum values are ame as dcb.Parity defines
                dcb.Parity   = static_cast<BYTE>(mParity);
                dcb.fParity  = (mParity == SerialCommBase::PRTY_NONE)? FALSE : TRUE;
                dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
                // ----------------------------------------------------
                // When running in win32 loopback with the simulator
                // in loopback mode, we must enable the RTS/CTS handshake
                // mode as there seems to be a 4K limit in the input
                // buffer when the DBU Simulator performs reads.
                // ----------------------------------------------------
                if (mFlowControl == SerialCommBase::FCTL_RTS_CTS) {
                    dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = 1;
                    dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
                }
                // Not absolutely necessary as the DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE is default
                dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
                isOK = SetCommState (mOsFileHandle, &dcb);
                if (isOK) {
                    COMMTIMEOUTS commTimeouts;
                    SecureZeroMemory(&commTimeouts, sizeof(COMMTIMEOUTS));
                    // These settings will cause ReadFile to return
                    // immediately if there is no data available at the port
                    // A value of MAXDWORD, combined with zero values for both the
                    // ReadTotalTimeoutConstant and ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier members,
                    // specifies that the read operation is to return immediately with
                    // the bytes that have already been received, even if no bytes
                    // have been received.
                    //isOK = GetCommTimeouts (mOsFileHandle, &CommTimeouts);
                    commTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
                    // ReadTotalTimeoutConstant - when set with a ms timeout value
                    // in conjunction with will ReadIntervalTimeout == MAXDWORD &&
                    // ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier set to 0 be used to control the
                    // timeout for the read operation.   Each time the read with a
                    // timeout is called, we compare the existing timeouts in CommTimeouts
                    // before changing it.
                    commTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
                    commTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
                    // timeouts not used for write operations
                    commTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
                    commTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
                    isOK = SetCommTimeouts (mOsFileHandle, &commTimeouts);
                    if (isOK) {
                        // test for asynchronous mode
                        if (mFlowControl == SerialCommBase::FCTL_OVERLAPPED) {
                            // allocate & initialize overlapped
                            // structure support for rx & tx
                            mpOverlappedTx.reset(new(OVERLAPPED));
                            mpOverlappedRx.reset(new(OVERLAPPED));
                            if (mpOverlappedTx && mpOverlappedRx) {
                                SecureZeroMemory(mpOverlappedTx.get(), sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
                                SecureZeroMemory(mpOverlappedRx.get(), sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
                                // create an unsignaled manual reset (2nd Param TRUE)
                                // event used for GetOverlappedResult. This event will
                                // be signaled by the ReadFile to indicate when
                                // IO operations are complete or encounter errors
                                mpOverlappedTx->hEvent = CreateEvent(
                                    NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
                                if (mpOverlappedTx->hEvent != NULL) {
                                    // now do the same for the RX side
                                    mpOverlappedRx->hEvent = CreateEvent(
                                        NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
                                    if (mpOverlappedRx->hEvent != NULL) {
                                        setState(COMM_OPENED);
                                        result = OS_SUCCESS;
                                    } else {
                                        result = handleError(deviceName);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    result = handleError(deviceName);
                                }
                                // close the handle and set error
                                if (result != OS_SUCCESS) {
                                    close();
                                    setState(COMM_OPEN_FAILED);
                                }
                            } else {
                                // close the handle and overlapped event
                                close();
                                setState(COMM_OPEN_FAILED);
                                result = OS_NO_MEMORY;
                            }
                        } else { // blocking mode
                            setState(COMM_OPENED);
                            result = OS_SUCCESS;
                        }
                    } else {
                        result = handleError(deviceName);
                        close();
                    }
                } else { // unable to set the baud rate or something
                    result = handleError(deviceName);
                    close();
                }
            }
        } else {
            result = handleError(deviceName);
            close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Here is the code that performs the timed read

```
    /**
     * Read a block of data into the specified raw buffer.
     * See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467(v=MSDN.10).aspx
     * for details for Overlapped IO usage, in particular note that setting
     * the timeout each time is tricky.
     *
     * @param pData     [in/out] data buffer
     * @param rNumBytes [in] buffer size
     * @param rTimeout  [in/out] timeout specified in milliseconds.
     *                  This parameter is updated to reflect the
     *                  remaining time.
     * @param rNumBytesRead
     *                  [out] number of bytes read
     *
     * @return OS_SUCCESS, OS_WAIT_TIMEOUT, OS_INVALID_ARGUMENT or
     *         OS_FAILED
     */
    OsStatus
    SerialCommWnt::read(
        void* pData,
        const size_t& rNumBytes,
        milliseconds& rTimeout,
        size_t& rNumBytesRead)
    {
        OsStatus result = OS_WAIT_TIMEOUT;
        rNumBytesRead = 0;
        DWORD numBytesRead = 0;
        DWORD commError;
        COMSTAT commStatus;
        auto startTime = system_clock::now();
        if (mpOverlappedRx) {
            // update the timeout used for ReadFile - note that the
            // magic combination that works for an absolute timeout is
            // MAXDWORD, timeoutMS, 0.
            COMMTIMEOUTS commTimeouts;
            GetCommTimeouts(mOsFileHandle, &commTimeouts);
            if (commTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant != rTimeout.count()) {
                commTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
                commTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant =
                    static_cast<DWORD>(rTimeout.count());
                SetCommTimeouts (mOsFileHandle, &commTimeouts);
            }

            // asynchronous overlapped IO mode.
            // reset the manual event to the non-signaled.
            // No Need for this as ReadFile resets it by itself
            // ResetEvent(mpOverlappedRx->hEvent);
            BOOL isOK = ReadFile(
                mOsFileHandle, pData, (DWORD)rNumBytes,
                reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(&rNumBytesRead),
                mpOverlappedRx.get());
            // get the result to date - only valid to call this
            // if ReadFile returns !isOK (FALSE) &&
            // last error set to ERROR_IO_PENDING
            //milliseconds elapsedTime;
            if (!isOK) {
                DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError();
                if (dwLastError == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
                    // pending IO, wait to complete using the COMMTIMEOUTS timer.
                    // when the COMMTIMEOUTS timer expires it will signal the 
                    // manual mpOverlappedRx->hEvent
                    DWORD ovlStatus = ::WaitForSingleObject(
                        mpOverlappedRx->hEvent, static_cast<DWORD>(
                            /*rTimeout.count()*/INFINITE));
                    switch (ovlStatus) {
                    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                        // timeout - update the remaining time to 0
                        rTimeout = milliseconds::zero();
                        result = OS_WAIT_TIMEOUT;
                        //elapsedTime = duration_cast<milliseconds>(
                        //    system_clock::now() - startTime);
                        break;
                    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                        // now that we have some data avaialable
                        // read it from overlapped IO
                        isOK = ::GetOverlappedResult(
                            mOsFileHandle, mpOverlappedRx.get(),
                            reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(&rNumBytesRead),
                            FALSE);
                        result = (isOK && rNumBytesRead>0)?
                            OS_SUCCESS : OS_FAILED;
                        //elapsedTime = duration_cast<milliseconds>(
                        //    system_clock::now() - startTime);
                        // update the remaing time (cannot be < 0)
                        rTimeout = std::max<milliseconds>(
                            rTimeout - duration_cast<milliseconds>(
                                system_clock::now() - startTime),
                            milliseconds::zero());
                        break;
                    default:
                        rTimeout = milliseconds::zero();
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (dwLastError == ERROR_HANDLE_EOF) {
                    ClearCommError(mOsFileHandle, &commError, &commStatus);
                    result = OS_FILE_EOF;
                } else {
                    ClearCommError(mOsFileHandle, &commError, &commStatus);
                    result = OS_FAILED;
                }
            } else { // Success
                //elapsedTime = duration_cast<milliseconds>(
                //    system_clock::now() - startTime);
                rTimeout = std::max<milliseconds>(
                    rTimeout - duration_cast<milliseconds>(
                        system_clock::now() - startTime),
                    milliseconds::zero());
                result = OS_SUCCESS;
            }
        } else { // sync mode
            BOOL isOK = ReadFile ( mOsFileHandle, pData, (DWORD)rNumBytes,
                reinterpret_cast<LPDWORD>(&numBytesRead), NULL);
            if ( isOK && (numBytesRead > 0) ) {
                rNumBytesRead = (size_t) numBytesRead;
                result = OS_SUCCESS;
            } else {
                ClearCommError(mOsFileHandle, &commError, &commStatus);
                // @JC Changed from simple test if lpErrors == 9)
                // which is equivalent to (CE_BREAK | CE_RXOVER)
                //if ((lpErrors & (CE_BREAK | CE_FRAME | CE_OVERRUN |
                //     CE_RXOVER | CE_RXPARITY)) != 0x00) {
                if (commError == 9) {
                    result = OS_FAILED;
    //              printf ("ClearCommError - lpErrors[%02x]", lpErrors);
                }
            }
            // update the remaing time (cannot be < 0)
            rTimeout = std::max<milliseconds>(
                rTimeout - duration_cast<milliseconds>(
                    system_clock::now() - startTime),
                milliseconds::zero());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (dwLastError == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
        DWORD ovlStatus = ::WaitForSingleObject(mpOverlappedRx->hEvent, ...);
        //...
    }
```

This is a very common mistake when programmers use overlapped I/O.  The core idea is that you use it to allow the device driver to start working on the job with the first ReadFile() call.  It is going to take a while, I/O always does, and especially with serial ports since they are very slow devices.

So you ask the driver "get started on it" and it goes about its job.  The driver will, eventually, signal it is done by calling the SetEvent() method on the OVERLAPPED.hEvent.  Which completes your WaitForSingleObject() call.

What you are *supposed* to do while the driver is working on it is *something else*.  Another job that your thread ought to do, something useful while the driver is working on the I/O request.  You can, for example, light up MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() with it.  Which pumps a message loop so your UI is still responsive.  And also tells you when the serial port has new data available.

The flaw in the code is that you could not figure out what else to do.  It immediately calls WaitForSingleObject() to wait for the overlapped I/O to complete.  Blocking the thread and not doing any useful work while the driver is working on the read request.  That's a very common problem.

In other words, you have not yet found a good reason to use overlapped I/O.  You will get **exactly** the same outcome by using a synchronous ReadFile() call.  It will block, just like your current code does, until the serial port has data available.

So just don't bother with it.  Fixes the timeout dilemma too.

Comment: That's not strictly true. While that is one use case for overlapped I/O, another is full-duplex serial port operation. In this case, it is perfectly ok to have a wait time on the `WaitForSingleObject` call if one thread is dedicated to reading from the port.

Comment: I realized that it is almost the same as using non overlapped IO, however the difference is (as my question mentioned), that I am trying to make this API similar in nature to its Linux counterpart which uses a select()/poll() system call to wait for data to arrive and be posted to the file handle - after which time the specified timeout is updated to reflect the remaining timeout.  Using the non overlapped method to do the same would require required repeated inefficient ReadFile/sleeps until the timeout expired or data arrived. In fact, prior to this I used to use the non overlapped method

Comment: Well, yes, that's what overlapped I/O is meant to do.  You however have to code your program very differently.  The point is that you *don't* wait for the I/O call to complete and poll.  Either with WaitForSingleObject() with a 0 timeout.  Or much more efficiently with a WaitForMultipleObjects().  The code you posted is nothing like that and can be much simpler with a blocking ReadFile call.

Comment: Thanks Hans, did you see the else block of the 'if (mpOverlappedRx)' where it comments // sync mode?  that is the simpler method which basically returns immediately with ReadFile results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comment straight out of the serial driver that might help you:

```
if (timeoutsForIrp.ReadIntervalTimeout == MAXULONG) {

//
// We need to do special return quickly stuff here.
//
// 1) If both constant and multiplier are
//    0 then we return immediately with whatever
//    we've got, even if it was zero.
//
// 2) If constant and multiplier are not MAXULONG
//    then return immediately if any characters
//    are present, but if nothing is there, then
//    use the timeouts as specified.
//
// 3) If multiplier is MAXULONG then do as in
//    "2" but return when the first character
//    arrives.
//
```

First, let's take a look at your synchronous read:

Assuming nothing messes with the `COMMTIMEOUT` values you set in your initialization, where the interval is set to `MAXDWORD` and everything else is 0, your synchronous `ReadFile` always returns immediately with any amount of bytes available, including 0 (case #1). If you had specified the read constant timeout then it would be used if no data was available, meaning your `ReadFile` call can timeout if no data arrives (case #2). Finally, if you set both the read multiplier and read interval to `MAXDWORD` then it is essentially a special case of #2, the `ReadFile` call returns when the first byte is there (so unless you are using a USB serial bridge or some pipe that can deliver a block of data, the bytes written value would most likely be 1).

Now, let's look at the asynchronous read:

For your asynchronous `ReadFile` call you need to know that the function will always return immediately regardless of the combination of `COMMTIMEOUT` values you have set. You are correct in the way you check for the `ERROR_IO_PENDING`. If the `ReadFile` call returns pending then you should wait on the overlapped object and get the overlapped result of the call. The difference between this and the synchronous `ReadFile` is that the overlapped read now has an added return value of `ERROR_IO_PENDING` returned in cases where the synchronous `ReadFile` would just block.

It seems like you are doing too many unnecessary modifications of the timeouts in your asynchronous method. I would just set a read constant timeout to a reasonable value and the rest to 0 on initialization only, and leave it alone. In the synchronous case it will block until data arrives or times out. In the asynchronous case it will return and you can post a wait which can timeout itself via `WAIT_TIMEOUT` or be signaled to be show completion of the original request with success, timeout or some other failure.

To additionally comment on what Hans was saying, the behavior here will be that a `ReadFile` that is not asynchronous will block in the serial driver and a `ReadFile` that is asynchronous will give you the opportunity to call `WaitForSingleObject`, but if you call this you are now blocking in your application. You will need to decide which is better for your solution.